# openCV Application error in hadoop 2.x (OutOfMemoryError)

Tags: java, opencv, hadoop, amazon-web-services, hipi

I want to make program that use template matching on hadoop. I use hipi with it.

But I run my program, I got the error "OutOfMemoryError" like below.

> CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception:
>   /home/ubuntu/opencv/opencv-2.4.11/modules/core/src/alloc.cpp:52:
>   error: (-4) Failed to allocate 67737604 bytes in function
>   OutOfMemoryError ]

if i tested with small number of pictures it work well both of local pc and server pc. And if I tested in my local PC which is setup for hadoop stand-alone with 300 pictures (about 300MB), it work well too.

But if I tested in server with 300 pictures, it worked well about 10~11 pictures, and then invoke like that errors.

if you want to see my code, you can see my code in github

https://github.com/kangilkueon/graduation_portfolio/blob/master/templateMatchingHadoop.java

Can you give me a help about this?

Comment: I am having problem testing opencv with hadoop. Can you help me regarding how you added opencv native library in hadoop program.  This is my question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36270351/opencv-library-loaded-in-hadoop-but-not-working